# Python string.format KeyError

Tags: python

This question has been answered before, but my string doesn't have any extra curly brackets that would mess up the formatting, so at the moment I'm completely clueless as to why the error

Error is KeyError : content

```
html = """
    <table class=\"ui celled compact table\" model=\"{model}\">
        {theaders}
        <tbody>
            {content}
        </tbody>
    </table>
    """
html = html.format(model=model)
html = html.format(content=data)
html = html.format(theaders=theaders)
```

Comment: *Aside*: The backslashes are not required in this example. Part of the benefit of triple-quoting a string is that any individual quote character is no longer special.

Comment: I just did them as part of trying to figure out the error :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you could do it line by line using a dictionary and passing the dict as keyword arguments using `**`

```
d=dict()
d['model']=model
d['content']=data
d['theaders']=theaders

html = html.format(**d)
```

Answer (score 7):

you  need to fill the values in one go:

```
html.format(model=model, content=data, theaders=theaders)
```

Comment: is there no way of doing it in parts?

Comment: @Mojimi Not directly via [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format). [Template strings](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.Template) have this feature using [`safe_substitute()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.Template.safe_substitute) but with a different placeholder syntax. But why do you need it?

Comment: yes, you could. you'd need to surround `content` with double brackets; `theaders` with four brackets (`{model}...{{content}}..{{{{theaders}}}}`). a bit of a hack...

Comment: Template strings are the answer!

Comment: @dhke Do you happen to know how to transform Template back to str to use with json.dumps? str() doesn't work

Comment: @Mojimi `Template.safe_substitute()` or `Template.substitute()` return a string (with the variables replaced). And the original string must be passed to the template, so I don't really know what you are asking.

Comment: @dhke but if it returns a string and not a template how can I do it in steps?

Comment: @Mojimi `html = Template(html).safe_substitute(model=model); html = Template(html).safe_substitute(content=data)`. But I really would suggest the approach from @jean-françois-fabre 's answer